# Postman Stuck on sending request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, postman

So, I try to post data from postman using raw and JSON/application type but it always stuck on sending request, and this is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const User = require('../models/user');

//Getting All
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const user = await User.find();
        res.json(user);
    }
    catch(err){
        res.status(500).json({ message:err.message });
    }
});

//Getting One
router.get('/:id',(req, res) => {
    res.send(req.params.id);
});

//Creating One
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const user = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber 
    });
    try{
        const newUser = await user.save();
        res.status(201).json(newUser);
    }
    catch(err){
        res.status(400).json({ message:err.message });
    }
});


//Updating One
router.patch('/',(req, res) => {

});

//Deleting One
router.delete('/:id',(req, res) => {

});


module.exports = router;
```

I'm stuck on postman when want to post JSON file data and I use node JS and express JS, and I use MongoDB as the database.
Can you guys help me to find the error in this code?

Comment: which API is failing?

Comment: can you tell us more about the error? Did you use `app.use(express.json())` aswell?

Answer (score 0):

use body-parser to solve your problem , if you don't use body-parser your body will be undefined and your code has error

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: 'true' }));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));
```

Comment: bodyParser is not needed for quite some time. ExpressJS already handles that. [Link](https://medium.com/@mmajdanski/express-body-parser-and-why-may-not-need-it-335803cd048c)